# Using multiple shrinkwrap modifiers on a single object

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

[image]

[image]

Here's an object I modeled with 3 different "surfaces' without using any modifiers. As you can see, the surfaces dont have a consistent curvature, especially closer to where they meet with another surface. One way I could fix this is by modelling the 3 surfaces separately and then shrinkwrapping specific parts of the mesh to each surface, which yields this result:
[image]

The surfaces are now consistent and match the curvature I'd like, but at the joints between surfaces there are obvious issues. Is there any way I can keep the clean smooth joints from the first picture while also using the shrinkwrap modifier? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to add a Smooth modifier after them? Or you can adjust the influence of the modifiers if you modify the vertex groups in Weight Paint mode. Try to decrase the values near the joints.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem with the first two images is supposed to be.

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc the surfaces arent as smooth as id like, they have weird ripples and are kind of distorted, which happens because the mesh topology isnt great, which is a byproduct of the surfaces being non-square or circular or etc.

Comment: From what I can see, there are only quads in your initial geometry. What kind of "ripples" are you talking about? Are you talking about the fact, that you are using flat shading?

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc the curvature of the object isnt smooth, which can be seen best on the blue surface, theres a light crease at the center of it for example

Comment: Then flatten them by using sculpting tools? The thing is that you have very little control over the shrinkwrap so thats pretty much no option.